# counting times the most frequent record appears in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2012 I have a table called `Deal_Country`. This table contains a field called `deal_id`, which is not a primary key. The same `deal_id` value can be in the table multiple times.

What I would like to know is the number that the most common `deal_id` is in the table.
 Please see example below.

```
 deal_id
 --------
 ABC12
 DFG34
 DFG34
 KNG10
 ABC12
 PPL11
 ABC12
```

The answer I would like returned is 3 as the most frequent `deal_id` (ABC12) is shown 3 times.

I have tried the query below however I get

```
"cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate 
 or a subquery."

select max(count(distinct deal_id))
from DEAL_COUNTRY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `order by` and `top`:

```
 select top 1 deal_id, count(*) as numtimes 
 from DEAL_COUNTRY
 group by deal_id
 order by count(*) desc
```

In MySQL, you would use `limit` instead of `top 1`.

Answer (score 1):

**MySQL Solution**:

`count` first, sort them from max to min and pick the top 1 record.

```
select deal_id, count(deal_id) deal_count 
  from deal_country
 order by 2 desc 
 limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This will handle a situation where there are 2 deals that are both at the top.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
       deal_id,
       count(*) as cnt 
    FROM DEALS
    GROUP BY deal_id
 )
 ,
cte2 AS (   
   SELECT
     deal_id,
     RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cnt desc) AS RankNumber
   FROM cte

)    
SELECT * FROM cte2 WHERE RankNumber = 1;
```

EDIT: forgot about WITH TIES. eg

```
 SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
    deal_id,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt 
 FROM DEALS
 GROUP BY deal_id
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```